# Agrupación resultados de consulta PHP en un JSON

Tags: php

me gustaría poder agrupar los resultados de una consulta a una tabla postgress para poder representarlos después en un gráfico.
Quiero representar dos datos: fecha y valor.
Paso como paramétros un campo (alfanumérico precargado en un select html) y una fecha que comprende un intervalo de tiempo y quiero obtener los valores.
Fichero PHP:

```
    $datos = $params["datos"];
    $date = $params["date"]."-10-01";
    
    $query="SELECT value, time::DATE FROM results WHERE alcance = 1"; 
            
    if($date){
        $query .= " AND time >= :date::timestamp without time zone 
                    AND time < :date::timestamp without time zone + INTERVAL '364 days' ";
        $params[":date"] = $date;
    }

    if($datos){
        $query .= " AND datos_code = :datos";
        $params[":datos"] = $datos;
    }
    $query .= " ORDER BY time";
    
    if ( $stm = $cnn->prepare( $query ) ) {       
        if( $stm->execute($params) ){
            $rows=array();
            while( $result = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $rows[] = $result;
            }
            if ($rows) {
                $data = $rows;
            } else {
                $data["error"]="No hay resultados para la búsqueda";
            }
        }else{
            $data["error"]="Error al ejecutar la consulta";
        }
        $statement->closeCursor();
        $conexion = null;
    } else {
        $data["error"]="Error al preparar la consulta";
    }
    echo json_encode( $data );
    exit();
```

El resultado que obtengo es:

```
[{"value":"9","time":"2020-10-01"},{"value":"9","time":"2020-10-02"},{"value":"9","time":"2020-10-03"}...]
```

Estuve viendo y probando a hacer una agrupación, probé con un array_to_string del modo:

```
$query="
    SELECT 
        array_to_string(array_agg(value), ','),
        array_to_string(array_agg(time::DATE), ',')
    FROM results WHERE alcance = 1"; 
            
    if($date){
        $query .= " AND time >= :date::timestamp without time zone AND time < :date::timestamp without time zone + INTERVAL '364 days' ";
        $params[":date"] = $date;
    }

    if($datos){
        $query .= " AND datos_code = :datos";
        $params[":datos"] = $datos;
    }
    $query .= " GROUP BY value, time";
```

Pero el resultado que me da es:

```
[{"array_to_string":"2020-10-01"},{"array_to_string":"20206-10-02"},{"array_to_string":"2020-10-03"}...
```

ni rastro del value ni de la agrupación.
**Lo que yo querría obtener para poder representar después en el gráfico sería algo del estilo**:

```
{
    "value":[9,9,9,...],
    "time":[2020-10-01,2020-10-02,2020-10-03,...]
}
```

Comment: Intenta con [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php): `$r = [ 'value' => array_column($data,'value'), 'time' => array_column($data,'time') ];`

Comment: @Sal lo que hice fue crear dos variables ```$values[] = $resultado['value']; $dates[]=$resultado['time']; ```  y después las relleno en el ```if($rows){ $data['value'] = $values; $data['time'] = $dates;``` ahora debería de convertir $values en datos numéricos porque me sale un string.